# "UnknownHostException" in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing, jmeter-5.0

I just started learning JMeter today. Wrote a simple web test - 10 user, 1 iteration to hit a webpage,
but in the "view result tree" I get "JMeter Response code: Non HTTP response code: java.net.UnknownHostException"

**Thanks in advance for helpers**[image: Thread group]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most probably you're behind a [corporate proxy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_server), your computer is not connected directly to the Internet, it is connected via special machine which grants Internet access to other computers over the network.

You need to make JMeter aware of this proxy, it can be specified at

1. "Advanced" tab of the [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler (or even better [HTTP Request Defaults](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/why-its-so-important-use-jmeters-http-request-defaults))

   [image]
2. Via [command-line arguments](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#configuring_jmeter) like:

   ```
   jmeter -H your-proxy-host -P your-proxy-port
   ```
3. Via [*system.properties* file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#configuring_jmeter) like:

   ```
   https.proxyHost=your-proxy-host
   https.proxyPort=your-proxy-port
   ```

More information: [Using JMeter behind a proxy](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#proxy_server)

Answer (score 0):

You might give a try using Chrome Plugin of Blazemeter.

1. Add Blazemeter Plugin to Chrome (You need to create free account on Blazemeter)
2. Record sample script
3. Download Script as .JMX
4. Try executing the script from your local version of JMeter

This helps with automatically recording browser proxies.